# Bug using Gson, Serialization and minified

Tags: android, android-studio, gson

At the beginning the app works fine(Emulator and physical device), but when I create the project  and upload the application to the play store, just stop working(Login App).

I found when:
minifyEnabled = true and upload the application the app always crash.

The app Crash with NullPointerException when GSON tries to deserialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this case you need to add this in your file proguard-rules.pro this line.

> `-keep class your.package.app.** { <fields>; }`

and in every file data class adding annotation

> `@Keep`

This problem occurs when minify applies use R8 for obfuscation change names and this causes parsing fails